# Fingerprint reader stop work after first attempt

Tags: xfce, gentoo, fingerprint

I'm using fingerprint reader on my Lenovo T495s laptop with Gentoo linux.
I use [fprintd](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/fprintd) service and it works well for login, unlocking screen etc.

Problem occurs when I did not place my finger properly on the reader at first attempt (the move of the finger is too fast or I use wrong finger). Then the message "Place your finger on the reader again." appears but from this time all subsequent attempts are unsuccessful. It looks like the reader is "frozen" and did not detect any attempt anymore.

In such case I have three options:

- I can type my password instead of using the finger. In such case the reader is not working anymore till I restart the computer.
- I can wait when the login attempt timed out, the XFCE screensaver dialog disappears and then the reader is working again. It takes like 1 minute or so.
- I can login to tty1 as root and run `killall -2 fprintd`. Then I do not need to wait for timeout and the reader start working again immediately.

I didn't found any useful info in /var/log/* files (maybe I do not have verbose loging enabled but I do not know where to enable it).

Can you advice me how to debug this issue? How to enable better logging or what I can try to find the reason of this behavior?

Comment: The symptoms look similar to another question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/632287/423679 So, probably, it is not specific to XFCE or Gentoo.